# Getting the original request URI with PrettyFaces

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, prettyfaces

I am using PrettyFaces in my JSF application. The site requires authentication to access some pages, so I'm using a listener (prerender view) that checks whether the user is logged in. So, if the user tries to access /foo (/foo.jsf before PrettyFaces), I redirect to /login.

However, I want to redirect them to their initial destination, so I want to attach a request parameter "next" so that I redirect the user to /login?next=/foo instead. Unfortunately, I can't get the original requestURI from the request object, the uri string in the following code is /appname/foo.jsf instead of /appname/foo

```
ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getRequest();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the original URI path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PrettyFaces uses under the covers [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to forward a pretty URL to the real URL. Using this technique, the original request URI is available as request attribute with the key [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI).

So, this should do:

```
String originalURI = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is indeed stored in the requestMap, however the key name was slightly different and given as a string. The following worked.

String originalURI = (String) ctx.getRequestMap().get("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");

Comment: Uhm, that's the same value as `RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`. See also the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI What exactly did you get when you sysout the value? Or did it just not compile? (that constant was introduced in Servlet 2.5).

Comment: Yes, it didn't compile, complaining about missing field. Strange, I thought I was already using Servlet 2.5 (have it in the dependencies), but maybe some other old version is overriding.

Comment: Perhaps you've placed an offending `servlet-api.jar` file in `/WEB-INF/lib`? Some starters do that. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I think my problem is a little different and maybe more involved, so I posted it as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741986/requestdispatcher-class-of-the-servlet-package-does-not-have-forward-request-uri

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, that constant was introduced in Servlet 3.0. It is indeed not present in Servlet 2.5 (Java EE 5). See also http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Comment: What happens if the request is forwarded twice?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to get the original request URL:

> **PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestUrl().toURL()**

Comment: In current prettyfaces the code is this 
    PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestURL().toURL()

Comment: Comparing this answer with BalusC's above there is a small but important difference. This gives the URL without the context path but using the forward request uri from requestMap contains the contextPath and jsessionid as well if cookie is disabled. So be careful when you choose a solution.

Comment: Also this solution gives the URL even there was no any prettyfaces effect. The solution based on forward_request_uri results to NULL.