# RequestDispatcher class of the servlet package does not have FORWARD_REQUEST_URI field

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, maven

I am trying to build a Java EE application using Maven. I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

According to http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI , the FORWARD_REQUEST_URI field should be there, however it isn't.

```
[ERROR] foo.java:[296,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable FORWARD_REQUEST_URI
location: interface javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher
```

There are no other jars inside the project directory. I unzipped the jar file found in ~/.m2 directory, and it has files dating back to 5/10/2006. When I delete the dependency from the pom.xml, it doesn't compile at all. (I have Glassfish server installed with Netbeans EE, so I may actually use the server's jars I suppose?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constant was introduced in Servlet 3.0. It's not present in Servlet 2.5, see also the Java EE 5 version of the [`RequestDispatcher` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html). If you're using Glassfish 3.x, which is a Servlet 3.0 container, then you should be able to update the version in pom to `3.0`. It's however supposed to be an `<scope>provided</scope>` dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot, due to this http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-182598336 I assumed servlet 3.0 was alpha. I included the following: 
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Hopefully, this should solve the strange problems I have been getting (running under Glassfish, it uses its own jars for servlet, right? I was constantly getting permgen errors + very slow deployment times.)

Comment: It was already finished at Dec 2009. Almost 2 years already. Glassfish 3 is a fullfledged Servlet 3.0 container. Using Servlet 2.5 dependencies on a Servlet 3.0 container is indeed asking for potential trouble.